# Getting bootstrap validation to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for my site and I'm busy creating a form. I have some required fields but if I submit my form without filling those fields I don't get a red box around the input field. But if I click on the input box I get the red box.

Here is my html

```
<li>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>* First Name</label>
    <div class="registration_firstName has-error">
        <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>
</li>

<button value="" class="registration_submit">Send</button>
```

Here is my js

```
$(".registration_submit").click(function(){
    var errorMsg = "";
    $(".error-success").hide();
    $(".has-error").each(function(index, element){
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
            errorMsg+= "error";
        }
        if($(this).attr("id") == "firstName"){
            errorMsg+= "error";
        }
    });

    if(errorMsg != ""){
        $(".submit").show();
        $(".error-success").html("please fill out the required fields.");
        $(".error-success").fadeIn(250);
        return false;
    }

    if($.trim(ajaxemail) == "success"){
        $(".submit").show();
        $(".error-success").html("Thank you. A confirmation email has been sent.");
        $(".error-success").fadeIn(250);
        $('#email').val("");
    }else{
        $(".submit").show();
    }

});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cerberus478/qrqbmjmw/3/)

Comment: How are you actually performing the validation?

Comment: I've added my js and updated my jsfiddle

Comment: It shows a red box, but I want a normal looking box and if there is nothing in the field then it has to go red

Comment: you need to remove the `has-error` class from html and add it only on validation, if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bootstrap extension for this:
http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

and use it like this:

```
$('form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I still get the same problem